# Show that $f(x)>f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Our function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)>0$. I want to show that there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0 < x < \delta$ we have $f(x)>f(0)$.

I don't know how to include the $\delta$ in the proof. Would you do proof by contradiction and assume $f(x) \le f(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(0)>0,
$$
then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-f'(0)\right|<\varepsilon \quad \forall 0<|x|<\delta.
$$
In particular for every $x$ such that $0<x<\delta$ we have

$$
f(0)+(f'(0)-\varepsilon)x<f(x)<f(0)+(f'(0)+\varepsilon)x.
$$
Since $f'(0)>0$, if we choose $\varepsilon$ such that $0<\varepsilon<f'(0)$ we obtain the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, take $f(0) = 0$ by a vertical shift. Then

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} > 0$$

By the definition of a limit, we see that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(h)$ is not negative for any $0 < h < \delta$. For if no such $\delta$ existed, there would be a sequence $h_n$ tending to $0$ with $f(h_n) \le 0$, in which case

$$f'(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(h_n)}{h_n} \le 0$$